# My customized ListView do not work in Fragment

Tags: listview, fragment

I copied code and class that have worked well in Activity(I altering my activities to fragment to use tab). But In Fragment, It does not work. There is no app crush, but any list do not appear on my display.
I already checked my database, it correctly worked. but nothing shown on my list. please help me. below are my code.

**ListFragment.java**

```
public class ListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

DBHelper mydb;
SQLiteDatabase db;

Intent retent;
private int amount;
private String date;
private String time;
private String use;
private ListView useList;
private ArrayList<history> histories;
private historyAdapter adapter;
private String checker;
private TextView upperBalance;

private int position=4;
private int onClickPosition;
private int itemcount;
private int amt=0;

public boolean bottomViewActivate = false;
public boolean monthlyActivate = true;

private int bottomViewId =0;
private TextView Arvitor;
private FrameLayout frameArvitor;
private ArrayList<history> historiesBackup;

private int CurrentYearMonthInt=0;
private int CurrentAddBalance=0;
public Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
public SimpleDateFormat intform = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM");
public SimpleDateFormat yearform = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
public SimpleDateFormat monthform = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
public SimpleDateFormat yearf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");
int year = Integer.parseInt(yearform.format(c.getTime()));
int month = Integer.parseInt(monthform.format(c.getTime()));

public ListFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page2, container,    false);
    year = Integer.parseInt(yearform.format(c.getTime()));
    month = Integer.parseInt(monthform.format(c.getTime()));
    CurrentYearMonthInt=Integer.parseInt(intform.format(c.getTime()));
    mydb = new DBHelper(getActivity());

    upperBalance = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListUpView);
    if(mydb.numberOfRows()!=0) {
        upperBalance.setText(" Current Balance : "+mydb.getRecentBalance()+"won");
    }else {
        upperBalance.setText(" Balance : 0won");
    }

    useList=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    histories = new ArrayList<history>();
    adapter = new historyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listsublayout, histories);
    useList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getActivity().registerForContextMenu(useList);
    histories=mydb.getAllUseList(bottomViewId,bottomViewActivate,monthlyActivate,CurrentYearMonthInt);
    itemcount=mydb.numberOfRows();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this problem.

But I can't understand why this solution work.
Anyway, I present how I solved this problem for whom being suffered by same problem.

I changed

histories=mydb.getAllUseList(bottomViewId,bottomViewActivate,monthlyActivate,CurrentYearMonthInt);

to

histories.addAll(mydb.getAllUseList(bottomViewId,bottomViewActivate,monthlyActivate,CurrentYearMonthInt));

Anyone who know why this solution work reply to my question, please.